Normal from geometry node working in Eevee but not in cycles
I have a procedural material that uses several edge detection maps obtained as the dot product of a bevel node and the normal vectors from a geometry node. As can be seen in the pictures, in the material preview view (rendered with eevee) and in the render preview (cycles), the material behaves wildly differently in certain faces of my mesh: it has unwanted large black areas in these faces, as if the normals of those faces were flipped (my normals are all good and the mesh is orientable):


This is confirmed by rendering the object with Eevee vs. Cycles:


If I convert the normal vectors from the geometry node into an HSV color, and render it, I get a well-behaved normal map in Eevee, while Cycles shows these funky areas where it looks like the normals are flipped:


So this has nothing to do with the material. But the geometry doesn't seem responsible either, because Eevee shows a well-behaved normal map, it'sas if there was a problem with Cycles... what's going on?

Hello. The bevel node doesn't work with EEVEE AFAIK so it doesn't mess up your normals. Try using a lower Bevel radius ? Also have you actually checked if the normals are all pointing the right way in your mesh ?

Hi, thanks for the reply, but the bevel node is not even involved in the last two pictures: I'm showing the normal map alone and it's messed up in Cycles but not in Eevee. As I said in the post, I checked the normals and they are all pointing outside.
